# Trying to replace a cracked light switch for my bathroom lighting

Tags: electrical, switch

The existing light switch once I removed it from the junction box has three black wires. There is no white nor green for ground connected to the existing switch. I see white wires bundled in the back of the box. I'm not sure how to rewire this safely.

Comment: Are two of the black wires together or quite close to each other?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box?